# Не отображается google карта на сайте

Tags: google-maps-api

Когда открываешь страницу, она есть. После обновления - исчезает и больше не подгружается. При наведении в окне карты вместо карты отображается белое окно.

Comment: -В нескольких браузерах

Comment: Если требуется дополнить вопрос, делайте правку вопроса, вместо того чтобы писать в комментариях. А по поводу вашего вопроса, посмотрите есть ли ошибки в консоли, если есть, добавьте текст ошибки к вашему вопросу, ну или дайте ссылку на сайт, тогда ваша проблема решится гораздо быстрее

Comment: http://будьте-уверены.рф/contacts

Comment: нажмите кнопку `править` под вопросом и добавьте туда все дополнения к вопросу, уточните в тексте вопроса что всё-таки у вас yandex карта да ещё и сайт на Битриксе

Answer (score 1):

странно. что автор не может Яндекс от Гугла отличить, а ещё это битрикс ...
предположительно какой-то плагин

вызов функции `init_MAP_mF8Ev4()` из консоли запускает карту

предполагаю, что для решения проблемы необходимо найти и отредактировать плагин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или просто добавить

```
setTimeout(()=>{init_MAP_mF8Ev4()},1e3)
```

а в идеале найти где вызывается `init_MAP_mF8Ev4()` и разобраться почему вызов функции идёт перед загрузкой библиотеки от яндекса